# How to restrict going back to login page after logged in in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want restrict users from going to back to login page after he/she logs in. How to do this using guard in routes ?

**My code :**

**guard.js**

```
export default function guard(to, from, next) {
    const  token  = localStorage.getItem('_utoken');
    if (token) {
        next();
    } else {
        next('/login');
    }
}
```

and in routes.js I used beforeEnter:guard inside every object except login route object like this

```
{
 path:'/home,
 name: 'Home,
 component: Home,
 beforeEnter: guard,
}
```

If token exists restrict from going to login page or signup page .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [`vue-router`: Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: My code is different

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding guard into each and every route, you can add a global guard to all routes:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>
{
  const  token  = localStorage.getItem('_utoken');
  if (!to.meta.public)
  {
    // page requires authentication - if there is none, redirect to /login
    if (token) next();
    else next('/login');
  }
  else 
  {
    // Login is supposedly public - skip navigation if we have a token
    if (token ? to.path !== '/login' : true) next();
  }
});
```

```
{
 path: '/home',
 name: 'Home,
 component: Home,
},
{
  path: '/login',
  name: 'Login',
  component: Login,
  meta:
  {
    public: true
  }
}
```